# FullCalendar update custom event data and trace deleted events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Maybe there is a better way to do this but I needed to mark an event as updated and deleted to be sent back to the server.

The event object from the server has an isUpdated property which is set to false and I am using the event object as is with the calendar.  Then for instance, when eventResize is triggered, I tried setting the flag to true and it did the job.  But at time of saving when i do a $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents") the isUpdated property is still false.  How to update custom data and persist?

```
eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {                                    
                event.isUpdated = true;
}
```

Also at time of saving I am also returning the clientEvents to the server but since the deleted events are no longer in clientEvents, how to go about sending back that information?  I have thought about using a mirrored object of the clientEvents but was hoping there is an easier way to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about save-as-you-go, via ajax, where changes to each event are sent one-by-one to the server at the moment where they are changed or deleted? Rather than waiting for one final submit, as you seem to be doing now. Either that or you'll have to create a separate array in your page of all the event IDs which are marked deleted. At the time when you tell fullCalendar to delete it, you can add the ID to your separate array simultaneously and then send that to the server at the end.

Comment: The requirement is to save all at one button click.  Yes making another object was my initial thought, again, just want to see if there is an easier way since from the way it looks now, getting the new object at time of saving wont be too easy due to how the page was designed.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "getting the new object at time of saving wont be too easy due to how the page was designed". Not sure I can see how that could be an issue. If the new array is a global there will be no problem.